# encontrar si 2 numeros dentro de un arreglo suman k e imprimir estos 2 números

Tags: c#

Hola estoy probando un ejercicio para verificar si la suma de 2 números dentro de un array es igual a K, y luego necesito imprimir estos 2 números los cuáles son los que lograron la suma.

```
static int[] myArray = new int[] {1,3,4,2,7,0};

public static void Main() {
  int k=10;
 for (int i = 0; i < myArray.Length; i += 1) {
     for (int j = 0; j < myArray.Length; j += 1) {
         // evitamos la comparación de un elemento consigo mismo
         if (i != j && (myArray[i] + myArray[j]) == k) {
             
             Console.Write("Los numeros son: "+ j,i);
         }
     }
 }
    
}
```

El me compara que la suma de los 2 números sea igual a 10 en este caso y me tira un mensaje cuando lo probé pero al intentar obtener los 2 números que son los que realizaron dicha suma me imprime un 4 y 1, cuando lo correcto debería de ser 7 y 1. Si me pueden orientar en qué estoy fallando lo agradezco!

Comment: Estás imprimiendo los índices del array, en lugar de imprimir el valor del array en ese índice. Prueba a imprimir myarray[j] y myarray[i]

Comment: @Jakala justo eso estoy probando, Console.WriteLine(" "+ myArray[i] , myArray[j]); de esta manera me los imprime, pero no lo hace de manera seguda, necesito que me los imprima así 3 7 (seguidos y con espacio) y me los imprime de la siguiente maner
3
7
(con salto de linea)

Comment: Logré hacer de esta manera @Jakala
 
Console.Write(myArray[i]);
break;

Pero me escribe 37 todo pegado, ocupo tenerlo separado

Answer (score 0):

Prueba de esta manera:

```cs
Console.WriteLine("Los numeros son: " + myArray[i] + " " + " " + myArray[j]);
```

Te imprimirá el 3 y 7 con espacio.